# not able to connect to mongodb cluster using bongo in golang project

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to connect to mongodb cluster from my project which uses bongo as the ODM.
It perfectly works for my local mongodb but when I give connection string as

```
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<url>/
```

it gives me "no reachable server error".

Any help is appreciated.

below is the code

```
config := &bongo.Config{
    ConnectionString: "<username>:<password>@<url>/test",
    Database: "test",
}
```

Comment: Please check connectivity between source and destination using  telnet ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the database name “test” from the ConnectionString parameter:

```
config := &bongo.Config{
    ConnectionString: "<username>:<password>@<url>",
    Database: "test",
}
```

Comment: Are the server running with the default port?